# Send Push Notification from Firebase to Android as well as iOS

Tags: android, ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notification to both android and ios. On Android push notification is handled by **data** while on ios **notification** is required in **payload** to display the notification.

But if notification part is added and if user is subscribed to the channel on both the device. On Android it show 2 messages created by notification part of payload.

Any particular way to send the payload from firebase. So that it can run on both the devices.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Firebase supports sending the same notifications to both iOS and Android. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message#send_a_notification_message

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen : I am able to send notification to ios and Android. But i don't want Firebase to use System notification tray. Notification will be created by data part.

Comment: Clarification needed: "On Android it show 2 messages". Are you saying that the *Android notification drawer* shows the message twice?

Comment: have you found an anwswer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Like Frank said, Firebase does support sending messages to both iOS and Android.

If you send a notification message with a data payload (so both notification and data) the Android client will **either** display the auto generated notification based on the notification payload if the app is in the background **or** be passed to the onMessageReceived callback where you have the option to generate a notification based on the data and/or notification payloads if you wish if the app is in the foreground. There will not be two notifications generated.

Comment: Seems to me that OP said that they *did* get two notifications. Shouldn't this be a *comment* on their question asking for clarification, rather than an *answer* (which appears to contradict OP's situation, therefore not applicable to them)?

Comment: ... I'm thinking their "notification" payload caused Android to generate a notification, and then they had code that processed the "data" portion (so their app was in background, and responded to the event, at which time they generated a "local notification" programmatically.)  Based on what I'm reading; haven't yet tried this myself, so looking for a good example of supporting BOTH platforms - have yet to find it, after searching and reading all day!! If you can show a bit of json that works on both platforms, that would be awesome - and a first. And clarify what callback does/doesn't do.

Comment: Hmm.  One issue. Without a notification payload, according to some posts, Android won't do anything, if your app has been *terminated* (so it isn't running in background). Though perhaps "auto-start" can solve that? Sorry, I'm not being clear:  there are *incompatibilities* between iOS and Android notification key requirements, so it seems the way to support both, is to put iOS keys in notification part, and Android keys in data (having app handle it). But if do so, Android will consider the notification part to be "incomplete" - it will either not display it, or display it poorly, I think.